# Connect to on Prem Microsoft Active Directory using Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, active-directory, ldap

I'm new to this and am trying to connect to an on Prem Microsoft Active Directory with Java spring boot.
the Active Directory is deployed on a remote server and I'm accessing the server using Microsoft Remote Desktop. Is there any way to establish a connection and authenticate the user?

Update:

i'm able to connect to AD but getting a NamingException

```
    String username = "test@myid.com.local";
    String password = "Yahoo@1234";
    String url = "ldap://100.36.224.125:389/dc=springframework,dc=org";
    String base = "ou=people,dc=example,dc=com";

    Hashtable<String, Object> ldapParams = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
    ldapParams.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    ldapParams.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
    ldapParams.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    ldapParams.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
    ldapParams.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

    // Specify SSL
    //ldapParams.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");

    InitialDirContext ldapCtx = null;



    try {
        ldapCtx = new InitialDirContext(ldapParams);
        System.out.println(ldapCtx);
        if (ldapCtx != null) {
            System.out.println("login success.");

            
            
            String searchFilter = "(cn=itadmin)";

            SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
            controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
            NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = ldapCtx.search(base, searchFilter, controls);

            while (results.hasMore()) {
                SearchResult searchResult = (SearchResult) results.next();
                Attributes attributes = searchResult.getAttributes();
                Attribute attr = attributes.get("cn");
                String cn = (String) attr.get();
                System.out.println(" Person Common Name = " + cn);
            }
        }
    } catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
        System.out.println("login fail. [err 1]");
        System.err.println(ex);
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        System.out.println("login fail. [err 2]");
        System.err.println(ex);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("login fail. [err 3]");
        System.err.println(e);
    } finally {
        System.out.println("LDAP Context is " + ldapCtx);
    }
```

Comment: Are you using any specific AD framework and what is the purpose of your program? The fact that you are using Remote Desktop has no relevance to your question.

Comment: thank you for the response. The purpose is to Authenticate the users on my app from the AD. im using Microsoft active directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using spring already you will probably want to follow [the spring guide to authenticating with LDAP](https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/).

What you should know is that Active Directory is a LDAP server as well.

The biggest problem with LDAP is to figure out what all the parameters should be.

Comment: Thank you so much ... i was able to connect to the AD but cant authenticate a user ... im getting NamingException. ive edited the question oo

Comment: Turns out i was using the wrong parameters. Thanks a bunch